# Inconsistent forecasts produced with Arima when xreg added

Tags: forecasting, arima

This should be straightforward but I don't see any reason why it doesn't work. Simple R datasets used as dummy data:

```
resultec=forecast::Arima(mdeaths[(1:60)],order=c(1,0,0),include.mean=FALSE,
xreg=fdeaths[(1:60)])
resultec

fore=forecast::forecast(resultec,h=12,xreg=as.vector(fdeaths[(61:72)]))

altfore=mat.or.vec(12,1)
altfore[1]=mdeaths[60]*resultec$coef[1]+fdeaths[61]*resultec$coef[2]
for (i in (2:12)){
altfore[i]=altfore[i-1]*resultec$coef[1]+fdeaths[60+i]*resultec$coef[2]
}
```

The forecasts produced by the forecast package are checked by a simple manual calculation here called "altfore". When "fore" and "altfore" are compared they do exhibit substantial differences. Could anyone guide me why? Thanks.

```
      fore  altfore
 [1,] 2175.011 2608.685
 [2,] 2076.797 2801.108
 [3,] 1922.694 2752.386
 [4,] 1618.415 2587.245
 [5,] 1264.026 2243.255
 [6,] 1134.441 1805.825
 [7,] 1070.973 1570.598
 [8,] 1002.219 1450.318
 [9,] 1039.240 1352.514
[10,] 1086.839 1365.912
[11,] 1287.812 1416.747
[12,] 1517.872 1629.998
```

Answer (score 2):

In `altfore`, you seem to be incorporating the lagged dependent variable directly and on equal terms with the exogenous regressor. That forms an *AR(1) model with an exogenous regressor*:

$$ y_t = \varphi_1 y_{t-1} + \beta_1 x_t + \varepsilon_t. $$

Meanwhile, the function `Arima` fits a *regression with an AR(1) error* when `xreg` is not `NULL`:

$$
\begin{align}
y_t &= \beta_1 x_t + u_t, \\
u_t &= \varphi_1 u_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t.
\end{align}
$$

These are different models, so no wonder the results in `fore` and `altfore` differ. See Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) for more details on the distinction between these types of models.

Comment: That is what I come to realise as well. Unfortunately, a regression with AR(1) error does not suit my purposes and inverting the lag operators is seriously time consuming. Isn't there a package/function that estimates and forecasts an actual ARIMA model in levels? Many thanks.

Comment: Actual ARIMA (without exogenous regressors) -- yes, regression with ARMA errors -- yes, but ARIMAX - I am not sure. I have seen this question before, perhaps you could find it in some earlier thread at Cross Validated.

Comment: Indeed I meant ARIMAX. It is a pity that standard R functions are defined for AR errors model only. Thank you for your advice nevertheless.